# Can I donate an ebook to my library's Overdrive collection?

Tags: library

My local library uses [overdrive](http://www.overdrive.com/), for ebook loans.  Can I donate an ebook I already own to them, or can I purchase an ebook specifically for my library?

Comment: The question is rather generic. It depends on the rights you have on the said book, the license under which you acquired it, the policy of the said library, the policy of the store and DRM, and so on.

Comment: What platform (i.e. Amazon) did you use to buy the book? What format is it?

Comment: I might need to do some more research on this.  I expected answer and comments to focus around the copyright of the book and overdrive as the intermediary.

Comment: It is also likely to depend on which country you are talking about, as they may have different copyright laws.

Comment: @JamesJenkins If expected "focus ... overdrive as the intermediary" I think it would be better to reduce the scope of the question and put that expectation in the question

Comment: @mark updated..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  If your library uses overdrive you can not give them ebooks to be loaned via Overdrive.  According to the [Overdrive FAQ](http://www.overdrive.com/libraries/public-libraries/faq/) only titles purchased from overdrive are available for library loans.

> Can I add the titles I purchased from another vendor to my OverDrive collection?
>
> Only titles purchased from OverDrive are licensed to be included in your OverDrive collection. You may upload proprietary content (e.g., lesson plans, podcasts, audio or video recordings, etc.) to your collection.

Overdrive is a subscription based service.  Each library creates it's own  custom digital collection, which is managed by the library staff.  Overdrive does not offer any services directly to library patrons so purchasing on behalf of the library is not an option.

You would need to contact your local library, you may be able to make a direct monetary donation in combination with a request to include a title in your library's collection.

> Does my digital library allow patrons to access OverDrive’s entire catalog of titles?
>
> OverDrive allows your library to create its own custom digital collection. Your team will be able to browse OverDrive’s extensive catalog of eBooks, audiobooks, music, and video and select titles based on your library’s collection development goals. Patrons will also have the opportunity to “recommend to library” the titles they would like to read that the library has not yet purchased. Ability to recommend titles varies by geographical location.

Comment: In general, from experience working with various libraries, they actually prefer monetary donations over any sort of media donation (physical or otherwise), as they have very specific needs and wants for their collections, and Joe Somebody's random books are very rarely it.

Comment: > In general, from experience working with various libraries, they
> actually prefer monetary donations over any sort of media donation
> (physical or otherwise), as they have very specific needs and wants
> for their collections, and Joe Somebody's random books are very rarely
> it. That makes sense in a world of limited physical shelf space, but in a world of infinite e-book space, I'd think libraries would be happy to take in whatever books that patrons wish to donate. In my case, I have the choice of buying the e-book for myself, reading it once and never reading it again, or buying it for